# Converting MBR disk to GPT using cmd

Tags: partitioning, conversion, mbr, windows-installation, gpt

I've converted my drive to GPT but when I partitioned the drive, at the point when I type in `active` it is giving me an error message saying

> The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk. The active command can only be used on fixed MBR disks

At first I ignored the statement and tried to install Windows 10 as it is I get the message saying

> we couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one, see the setup log files.

Answer (score 1):

The [active flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_flag) is only used in MBR where bootloaders are very simple (as they have to fit into the 446-byte space in the tiny boot sector) and uses that flag to load the OS in the active partition. It's clear from the error output

> The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk. The active command can only be used on fixed MBR disks

OTOH **there's no concept of *"active"* disk on GPT**. The boot order information is stored in UEFI flash and [ESP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition). The ESP is also large so bootloaders can be complex and doesn't have to load the next stage in the [EBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record)

You said that you converted the drive but **what command did you use**? If you used the built-in [MBR2GPT.EXE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt) then after the conversion the partitions should be the same as before, and if there isn't a free partition to install the new Windows then installation will fail